# Kill Process that is created from running a task

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I am launching a task and it works great but its a task that stays running in the current shell. Is there anyway to kill this task from the editor when you are done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885264/how-to-set-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-terminate-running-task-in-vscode

Comment: Yeah debugger is annoying for me when it spawns. For a server I use lsof -i tcp:3333 (or whatever the port is) and then kill -9 PID

Answer (score 8):

Try `Ctrl+Shift+P`, start typing `term` and the command palette will highlight "terminate running task", press `Enter` and you're done

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if you have tried.

1. Press `Ctrl+P`.
2. Type `>task terminate`.

Comment: Typing `>` in [Quick Open](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_explorer) `Ctrl+P` is the equivalent of [Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_command-palette) `Ctrl+Shift+P` (for others like me who missed typing `>`)

Answer (score 3):

In the task Runner Explorer window, you'll see a tab that has "(running)" in it's title. Click the X to close the tab, and visual studio will ask you if you want to terminate the task.  If you chose to terminate it, the tab will disappear.

Answer (score 2):

To kill a C++ Code Runner task, press Ctrl + Alt + M.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You can end the task using the bin button!