# How to Set a Keyboard Shortcut to "Terminate Running Task" in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I have my build run my application until I kill it. This works fine, but it would be nice to bind "Terminate Running Tasks" to a keyboard shortcut. Is this possible?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46899480/vscode-terminal-terminate-process-without-prompt/52735332#52735332 for a method to bind killing a task and accepting the terminate? prompt with a single keybinding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All the commands are listed when you go to change a key binding, so you can add something like this to the user settings:

```
[
    { "key": "shift+cmd+s", "command": "workbench.action.tasks.terminate" } 
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also just write `exit` in the terminal and that would kill it. Just keep in mind that this might not work on everything but it's worth a try ;)