# vscode terminal: terminate process without prompt

Tags: visual-studio-code, command-line-interface

I'm used to terminating a process in the CLI by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> twice but that doesn't work in vscode's integrated terminal. It prompts for confirmation. Is there a way to use it the same way? Or even better, with 1 keypress.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like the prompt will be automatically replied to in vscode v1.64.  See [Auto-replies in Release notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_64.md#auto-replies):

> #### Auto replies
>
> The terminal is now able to automatically reply when a specific
> sequences of characters is received. A good example of where this is
> useful, which is also the only default case, is the Windows batch
> script message `Terminate batch job (Y/N)?` after hitting ctrl+c when
> running a batch script. This typically just ends up causing problems
> for the user. The terminal will now automatically reply with `Y` and
> enter (`\r`) which makes ctrl+c in Windows feel much better.

[image: terminal auto-reply demo]

> The feature was made generically so you can setup custom replies for
> other thing, just be careful when doing this as you are sending text
> to the process automatically. For example you could use it to
> automatically update Oh My Zsh when prompted:

```
"terminal.integrated.autoReplies": {
  "[Oh My Zsh] Would you like to check for updates? [Y/n]": "Y\r"
}
```

> If you use Clink and enable their similar feature, you can disable it
> in Clink or in VS Code by setting the reply to null to avoid the two
> features conflicting with each other:

```
"terminal.integrated.autoReplies": {
  "Terminate batch job (Y/N)": null
}
```

- So it looks like you set the corresponding message to `null` to **disable** the automatic reply.

> [set default to null](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/142341): looks like they are changing the default to disabled.

---

## Without extensions:

add `"workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence"` to the `terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell` list in your settings.json by going to File → Preferences → Settings, then searching for the string `terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell`, and then clicking "edit in settings.json".

If there is no `"terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell"` entry in your settings.json, simply add it:

```
... ,
"terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell": [
  "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence"
]
```

Then you will also need to add the following key binding (File → Preferences → Keyboard Shortcuts → open keybindings.json):

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+c",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": {
        "text": "\u0003Y\u000D"
    },
    "when": "terminalFocus && !terminalTextSelected"
}
```

Note that this solution requires you to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> **twice**, and only works in the Visual Studio Code terminal.

This will also change the behaviour for any tool you run in the terminal that relies on two <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> instructions: as you are now sending the capital letter `Y` and a newline as second instruction instead, make sure whatever you're running has an alternate means of exiting available.

## With extensions:

You can use the [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command&WT.mc_id=vscodecandothat-dotcom-team) extension, by adding this setting:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [
  {
    "command": "multiCommand.terminateTerminal",
    "interval": 1000,
    "sequence": [
      {
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
        "args": {
          "text": "\u0003"
        }
      },
      {
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
        "args": {
          "text": "Y\u000D"
        }
      },
    ]
  }
```

The `interval` provides a pause between the two `sendSequence` commands, and both commands are required:

- `u\003` is an End of Text (Caret = ^C).
- `u\000D` is a <kbd>Return</kbd>.

Then add a keybinding in keybindings.json:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+c",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.terminateTerminal" },
},
```

Certain key combinations will **not** work (like the standard sequence of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> twice), but with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, whether the cursor focus is in an editor, the file explorer, or the terminal it works well.

Note that this does not kill or close the terminal or affect its history, it just stops the current job there.

Comment: I tested your suggested edit and it doesn't work - definitely needs the interval.  The interrupt does not complete fast enough to take the next input (Y\000D).  Plus focus is usually in an editor when I want to interrupt the process so the ctrl+shift+c version is really pretty handy.

Comment: Ah, it wasn't apparent that were doing that twice given the text arg - which I guess is being sent twice in full.

Comment: Do note that this solution will interfere with things that themselves rely on ctrl-c, like node.js: running node in a terminal in VS Code and hitting ctrl-c twice to exit it will now lead to sending the input `Y` instead. (there are, of course, other ways to exit node specifically, but if you're running a REPL that listens for ctrl-c, remember that you'll be disabling that functionality with this fix)