# How to re-use a VS Code task window, without closing it

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

My goal is to re-use a task window in VS Code. However, when I enter ctrl + c, the task stops, but then writes: "**Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.**".

I don't want to close the window. It's frustrating because it forces me to open a new window and navigate to the correct directory.

I recorded a gif of the problem (It's the window on the right):

[image]

My task config look like this:

```js
{
    "label": "some label",
    "type": "npm",
    "script": "build",
    "path": "some-path/",
    "problemMatcher": [],
    "runOptions": { "runOn": "folderOpen" },
    "group": "build",
    "presentation": {
        "echo": true,
        "reveal": "silent",
        "focus": false,
        "panel": "shared",
        "showReuseMessage": false,
        "clear": false,
        "group": "build"
    }
}
```

I tried various combination of the `presentation` properties, but to no help.

Related feature request on VS code is [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/86379).

Comment: It looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46899480/vscode-terminal-terminate-process-without-prompt/52735332#52735332 Try the macro solution, that is the easiest - let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible and it *may* be by design.

If you look at the [schema of tasks.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks-appendix), you see:

```js
/**
 * The description of a task.
 */
interface TaskDescription {
  /**
   * The task's name
   */
  label: string;

  /**
   * The type of a custom task. Tasks of type "shell" are executed
   * inside a shell (e.g. bash, cmd, powershell, ...)
   */
  type: 'shell' | 'process';

  //...
}
```

> The type of a custom task. Tasks of type "shell" are executed inside a shell

So to me this implies that if you have a countdown task of type "shell" running this command `seq 10 1`, behind the scene it would do:

```
devbox:~ dev$ bash -c "seq 10 1"
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
devbox:~ dev$
```

As you can see it immediately exits and I'm not sure you can do anything about it. (I may be wrong though)

Even if you set a task of type "process" (command being the path to an executable), it doesn't allow you to reuse the terminal.

Having said that you *can* force it but VS Code wouldn't be too happy about it: (notice the `&& sh` at the end of the command)

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {

      "label": "10 9 8 ...",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "seq 10 1 && sh",
      "presentation": {
        "echo": true,
        "focus": true,
        "reveal": "always",
        "panel": "shared",
      },
      "problemMatcher": [],
    }
  ]
}
```

When you run the task, you do get another shell immediately:

[image]

However if you re-run the same task, then VS Code gets grumpy:

[image]

The fact that I couldn't see an option in `.vscode/settings.json` to support your use case makes me think that it really is a *by design* choice:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found  a solution for this, my task looks something like this

```js
"tasks": [
        {
            "label": "start server",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "RUN='cd backend && npm run dev' bash",
            "problemMatcher": [],
        },
   ]
```

and at the end of my .bashrc I have `eval "$RUN"`

Answer (score 1):

I found yet another solution for this that works great for me:

1. using bash:

   ```
   "tasks": [
       {
           "label": "start server",
           "type": "shell",
           "command": "bash -c 'cd backend && npm run dev; exec bash'",
           "isBackground": false,
           "presentation": {
               "panel": "new",
               "close": true
           },
           "runOptions": {
               "runOn": "folderOpen"
           }
       }
   ]
   ```
2. or if you use fish (like me):

   ```
   "tasks": [
       {
           "label": "start server",
           "type": "shell",
           "command": "fish -C 'cd backend && npm run dev'",
           "isBackground": false,
           "presentation": {
               "panel": "new",
               "close": true
           },
           "runOptions": {
               "runOn": "folderOpen"
           }
       }
   ]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to launch a shell in the right folder after the task is complete. I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but I do something similar with compound tasks.

```
{
    "label": "some label",
    "type": "npm",
    "script": "build",
    "path": "some-path/",
    "problemMatcher": [],
    "runOptions": { "runOn": "folderOpen" },
    "group": "build",
    "presentation": {
        "echo": true,
        "reveal": "silent",
        "focus": false,
        "panel": "shared",
        "showReuseMessage": false,
        "clear": false,
        "group": "build"
    }
},
{
    "label": "shell",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "cd app; bash",
    "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
    }
},
{
    "label": "Task and Shell",
    "group": "build",
    "dependsOn": ["some label", "shell"],
    "dependsOrder": "sequence",
}
```

This configuration runs bash in the right folder after the task (in the same window). Replace `bash` with whatever shell you use if necessary.

Comment: I tried to implement your solution, but it does not seem to keep the window open?

Comment: Just checking: Are you running the composite task? Or the original task?

Comment: I am unsure about your question?