# How to stop VS Code from prompting twice when terminating a batch job?

Tags: visual-studio-code, command-line-interface

Typically, when I use the CLI and type CTRL+C, I get a prompt that says

> Terminate batch job (Y/N)?

I then type `y` and it terminates. In only one of my projects, it duplicates the prompt every single time. Why is it doing this? How can I remove this extra step and only do it once when I need it?

[image: Image of the duplication]

Honestly, I haven't tried anything other than some googling, because I don't know how to fix this problem.

Comment: Do you need to type 'y' both times, or is it just a display thing?

Comment: That's a good question. I think the program stops the first time from what I can tell in the terminal, and the window has closed.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52735332/836330 to set up an auto reply to that terminate prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Set an auto reply to this by adding this in your `settings.json`

```
 "terminal.integrated.autoReplies": {
        "Terminate batch job (Y/N)": "Y\r"
    },
```